# How to force activity always appear in portrait orientation without delay in lockscreen?

Tags: android, orientation

I have an activity with "portrait" orientation in AndroidManifest.xml.
When I start it from lock screen in landscape orientation, it appear with landscape for 1 second, and then change to portrait. The delay happens even if it's an blank activity (no view, no task).
[image]

Tell me how to avoid this delay. Remove transition effect, rotation effect? I know it could be device performance, but still want to fix this.

Comment: If you want to fix the orientation landscape then give this attribute in activity declaration in menifest file android:screenOrientation="landscape"

Answer (score 2):

If you always wants to run your app in landscape mode than use this code in Manifest file for all activity

```
        <activity
        android:name=".yourAcitvity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        />
```

Comment: But because my app support portrait only, the landscape isn't acceptable :)

Comment: Ok if you want your activity to be in portrait mode always then change the screenOrientation = "portrait"  in manifest

Answer (score 1):

That't the default behavior of Android, you can verify this issue using system apps. For ex: open the Android's default messenger, and turn it to landscape and lock the phone, now unlock it and you can see the messenger has re aligned to portrait, that's because the home screen is set to portrait by default. In order to show the home screen the system aligns the device to portrait again.